# C++ classes - how to pass vector of custom type to function

Tags: c++, class, parameters, vector, arguments

I am attempting to develop a class with a function that can take a vector of items as it's argument.

I can get it to work fine if I use a vector of type int, or other primitive, but I can't get it to work with a vector of objects.

eg:

In my header file:

```
int influenceParticles(vector<Particle> particles);
```

This is what I am after, but won't compile (error stated is `"'Particle' was not declared in this scope"`).

The particle.h file has been included at the top of this header file.

**Clarification**

Here is the .h file that gives me the error

```
#ifndef _PARTICLE_ATTRACTOR
#define _PARTICLE_ATTRACTOR

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "particle.h"


class ParticleAttractor {

    //private
public:

    ParticleAttractor(int posX, int posY); //constructor (void)

    int influenceParticles(vector<Particle> particles);

};


#endif
```

Comment: Please cut and paste the absolute shortest complete program you can construct that displays the error. Hint: you should be able to get it down to 6 or 7 lines.

Comment: Does your particle.h file also include the header file with influenceParticles ?

Comment: You should probably include vector.h directly and qualify vector as std::vector if that is indeed std::vector.

Comment: @Slavik81:  +1 on the qualification of vector and the need to include the header, but it is `#include <vector>` without the h, the h was never in the standard and is allowed in compilers only for backwards compatibility with pre-standard code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you have cyclic includes, ie. if the ParticleAttractor.h also includes the Particle.h. To solve this, you should make a forward declaration of Particle in ParticleAttractor.h:

```
class Particle;
```

You should also consider passing the vector by reference to avoid copying:

```
int influenceParticles(vector<Particle>& particles);
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I was after. Also thanks for the reference tip

Answer (score 0):

First `Particle` must be a defined type. This definition should work:

```
int influenceParticles(vector<vector<int> > particles);
```

For practice, it is better to use the by reference parameter type rather than by value. So it is better to define it as:

```
int influenceParticles(vector<vector<int> >& particles);
```